# Accessing associated class with scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, rails-activerecord

```
class A
    scope :scope_name -> {scope_condition}
end

class B
  has_many :a
end
```

i need to access A through B with A's scope?, like

when i call `B.last.a` it should fetch me `B.last.a.scope_name` results.

can it be done without using default_scope or conditional association `(has_many :a -> {scope_condition})`?

Comment: You gave the answer yourself by the way... why isn't that working for you?

Comment: Why not just override the `:a` method? BTW, it should probably be `has_many :as` (plural, not singular).

Comment: Can you be more specific about why a default scope or conditional association isn't suitable? That would help us understand which similar solutions also won't work.

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't be done without default_scope, conditional relation, or instance method on B.

Like you said, when you would call:

```
a_with_scope = B.find(1).a.scope_name
```

You'll get the scoped version of A, but if you want to find the exact same result  by calling `B.find(1).a`, you indeed need to set default scope on model A, or create condition on the relation, or create method on B:

```
class B
  def a_scoped
   a.with_scope
  end
end
```

Comment: So, the OP said *"when i call `B.last.a` it should fetch me `B.last.a.scope_name`"*. Does this do that?

Comment: I think OP wants to not call `.scope_name`, as he said "when I call `B.last.a`, it should fetch me `B.last.a.scope_name` results." I wonder though why he wouldn't want to use the `.scope_name`

Comment: Agree... didn't read past first question. Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: *"can it be done without using default_scope or conditional association?"*

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a scope to A temporarily with [`scoping`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-scoping):

```
A.scope_name.scoping do
  # some time later..
  B.last.a # this (and any other use of A) will be scoped with scope_name
  # ...
end
```

This will act like a default scope, with many of the same considerations and gotchas, but it isn't application-wide.